# Strategy for updating data in databases (Oracle)

Tags: oracle

We have a product using Oracle, with about 5000 objects in the database (tables and packages). The product was divided into two parts, the first is the hard part: client, packages and database schema, the second is composed basically by soft data representing processes (Workflow) that can be configured to run on our product.

Well, the basic processes (workflow) are delivered as part of the product, our customers can change these processes and adapt them to their needs, the problem arises when trying to upgrade to a newer version of the product, then trying to update the database records data, there are problems for records deleted or modified by our customers.

Is there a strategy to handle this problem?

Comment: What do you want to do id the customer has updated a row and your upgrade scripts want to update the same row?  Are you going to let the customer's row rule?  Or do you want your update to rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common for a software product to be comprised of not just client and schema objects, but data as well; typically it seems to be called "static data", i.e. it is data that should only be modified by the software developer, and is usually not modifiable by end users.

If the end users bypass your security controls and modify/delete the static data, then you need to either:

1. write code that detects, and compensates for, any modifications the end user may have done; e.g. wipe the tables and repopulate with "known good" data;
2. get samples of modifications from your customers so you can hand-code customised update scripts for them, without affecting their customisations; or
3. don't allow modifications of static data (i.e. if they customise the product by changing data they shouldn't, you say "sorry, you modified the product, we don't support you".

From your description, however, it looks like your product is designed to allow customers to customise it by changing data in these tables; in which case, your code just needs to be able to adapt to whatever changes they may have made. That needs to be a fundamental consideration in the design of the upgrade. The strategy is to enumerate all the types of changes that users may have made (or are likely to have made), and cater for them. The only viable alternative is #1 above, which removes all customisations.